# VB.NET Display query result in Combobox using Paramaterized Stored Procedure

Tags: vb.net, stored-procedures, parameters, combobox

I want to display the result of my query in my Combobox but I'm getting an error "invalid argument or no parameter passed". Any advice is greatly appreciated. Here's my code.

```
Private Sub frmAdvancePayment_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    lstBillNum.Items.Clear()
    txtLName.Text = frmAmortizationFee.txtLName.Text
    txtFName.Text = frmAmortizationFee.txtFName.Text
    lblMaAmount.Text = frmAmortizationFee.txtAmort.Text
    lblAcctNum.Text = frmAmortizationFee.cmbAccountNo.Text


    Dim connection_string As String = "Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=CreditAndCollection;Integrated Security=True"

    Dim Connection As New SqlConnection(connection_string)
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim command As New SqlCommand
    command.Connection = Connection

    command.CommandText = "showBillingNum"
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AcctNum", lblAcctNum.Text)

    Connection.Open()

    da.SelectCommand = command
    Dim dt As New DataSet
    da.Fill(dt)

    cmbBillNum.DataSource = dt

    cmbBillNum.DisplayMember = "BillNum"
    cmbBillNum.ValueMember = "BillNum"
    command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Connection.Close()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would guess it is working but you are getting the error still?  This is because the 3rd to last line:

```
command.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

executes the query after it has already been run.  Not sure why that would produce that error but I know that line is wrong.